# Best way to call function with variable execution time at minimum intervals in Golang?

Tags: go, timer

I want to execute a function at *no less than* a given interval in Go, measured by the start of one invocation to the start of the next invocation. The function itself will vary in its execution time.

If the function runs for longer than that interval, I want to run it again immediately. But if/when it eventually resumes completing in less than a full interval, I want it to immediately resume waiting until the next interval-boundary.

For context, this is a rate-limiter-- the called function could easily spin the CPU but it wouldn't produce additional value, as it's interacting with humans who can't possibly react that fast.

An example for clarity (`interval == 20ms` in example):

```
runtime:  15ms
wait:      5ms
runtime:  25ms
wait:      0ms
runtime:  25ms
wait:      0ms
runtime:  15ms
wait:      5ms <-- this is the important bit
```

If I use `time.Ticker`, I believe additional "ticks" will either queue up in the `Ticker.C` channel (if it's buffered) causing it to make a bunch of invocations with no delay when it resumes, or the Ticker's writer will block on writing to the channel and end up resuming with an over-long delay for the first invocation afterit resumes.

Right now I'm doing some math, which is working, but it feels like it might be un-idiomatic:

```
minDurationBetweenRuns := time.Millisecond * 100
for {
    lastRunTime := time.Now()

    DO_STUFF_HERE()

    durationSinceLastRun := time.Now().Sub(lastRunTime)
    if durationSinceLastRun < minDurationBetweenRuns {
        sleepTime := minDurationBetweenRuns - durationSinceLastRun
        if sleepTime > minDurationBetweenRuns {
            sleepTime = minDurationBetweenRuns
        }
        time.Sleep(sleepTime)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While writing the question, I remembered that the Golang source is super easy to read... and figured I should just have a peek before looking silly. I am pleased with what I found :)

Comments in [the source](https://golang.org/src/time/tick.go?s=818:970#L16) for `time.Ticker` say if the tick-reader falls behind it will start dropping ticks rather than blocking on writing to the channel (which has a buffer of only 1). The effect of this is to get things back "on track" immediately after we've missed one or more ticks.

Example proof:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 50)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("New invocation starting at %dms\n", time.Now().Round(time.Millisecond).Nanosecond()/int(time.Millisecond))
        if i%3 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Executing for 25ms")
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 25)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Executing for 75ms")
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 75)
        }
        fmt.Println("Waiting for ticker...")
        <-t.C
    }
    t.Stop()
}
```

Output:

```
New invocation starting at 0ms
Executing for 25ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 50ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 125ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 200ms
Executing for 25ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 250ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 325ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 400ms
Executing for 25ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 450ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 525ms
Executing for 75ms
Waiting for ticker...
New invocation starting at 600ms
Executing for 25ms
Waiting for ticker...
```